# "Let us do start" Right or wrong

Tags: grammar, emphatic-polarity

> "Let us do start"

Is this sentence has any error?

This is a message send by my English teacher in a group. I asked from the teacher that it is true or not. The teacher answered me that it is true. "Do" is used for making sentence emphatic.

Is this correct?

Comment: Your question would be better without all the dialogue in your own language.  The emphatic use of _do_ would result in "Do let us start" - your teacher's version is not idiomatic English.

Comment: I agree with Kate and I would also point out that you should not post images of text as they cannot be read by the software user by those who are visually impaired. Please transcribe them before posting. CHATGPT is not necessarily a reliable source, in this case it is correct.

Comment: I've edited.  The dialogue was irrelevant to the question. I've also replace all the HTML formatting with markdown. It's much easier.  Finally, you should check your grammar of "Is this sentence has any error"  This sentence should be "Does this sentence have any error".  Think about the grammar here.

Comment: It's not grammatical.  The "do" would have to go before "Let us".

Comment: What do you mean a message sent by my English teacher **to** a group? If kids are making noise, it could be used in speaking. Let's do [action verb] [with or without another phrase]

Comment: I think there is a subtle grammar point here.  "Let us do begin" is certainly wrong. As is "I made him do come" or "He helps her do read".  But the forms without do support are valid.  However the same sequence of words is possible with "Let's do begin with some easy questions."  at least in speech.  As is "Do let's begin".  I shall consider this further.

Answer (score 4):

No native English speaker would say "Let us do start" it's just wrong.

"Let us do [action]" is never used, but "Let us do [noun / noun phrase]" is OK, for example "Let us do question 3".

It is possible to say "Do let us [verb]", (with an emphasis on **do**) which would be understood as an expression of impatience or frustration that some action hasn't begun yet. For example "Do let us begin".